# GC#copyArea in Headless Mode

Tags: swt

I've created a control to display images, and to test it I create "screenshots" of the control and compare them to what I expect them to be. Sreenshots are created like this:

```
protected Image createScreenshot(Control control) {
    final GC gc = new GC(control);
    try {
        final Point size = control.getSize();
        final Image result = new Image(control.getDisplay(), size.x, size.y);
        gc.copyArea(result, 0, 0);
        return result;
    } finally {
        gc.dispose();
    }
}
```

It works nicely when started from the IDE, but when started in headless mode from our CI server, the image does not render. I tried taking a picture of the surrounding `Shell`, but a screenshot of the `Shell` is a white image, too.

I tried the following methods to try to get the screenshot to work:

```
    Control#redraw();
    Control#update();
```

They did not work.

Is there any way to render controls even in headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the controls are not painted on the screen that's why you see a blank image.

I think your problem is similar to this:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/162790/

In order to solve it you should follow this link:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/CI_Server

Good luck